# Is their any way to fetch master data from Tally Prime ranging between ALTERID's through XML Request

Tags: xml, accounting, tally

Is there any way to fetch the master data like Ledgers from tally ranging from xyz AlterId to abc AlterId or the Ledgers whose alterId is greater then xyz AlterId?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert Exactly what you required into a TDL Formula and Filter Masters Based on That Formulae

```
$ALTERID &gt; '100'
```

`&gt;` is escaped text of >

If you want filter between Range(Ex:100 to 120) then

```
$ALTERID &gt; '100' AND $ALTERID &lt; '120'
```

If you go any problem then try removing quotes for `$ALTERID &gt; 100`

Final XML will look like

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>Collection</TYPE>
        <ID>CustMasterColl</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CustMasterColl">
  <!-- * Tally Masters Types like Ledger, Group, StockItem ..etc., -->
                        <TYPE>Ledger</TYPE>
                        <FILTERS>Masterfilter</FILTERS>
                    </COLLECTION>
<!-- * IF you want Between then $ALTERID &gt; '100' AND $ALTERID &lt; '120' -->
                    <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="Masterfilter">$ALTERID &gt; '100'</SYSTEM>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```